# WooCommerce - Line of text keeps repeating on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, checkout

I want to insert "If you'd like to change your subscription, go back to Cart" on my checkout page. I inserted it in the `review-order.php` file, but it repeats on the checkout page even if I only inserted the line once in the document.

[image: This picture shows how the text repeats]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'd like to show the text at the top of the section *(before the table)*. 
Thanks in advance!

**Here is the code:** (the top line is what I added)

```
    <?php echo "<strong>If you'd like to change your subscription, go back to <a href='https://sprinly.com/cart/'>Cart</a></strong> </br>"; ?>


<?php
/**
 * Review order table
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>



<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                        <td class="product-name">
                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                            <?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-total">
                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }

            do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>



        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && 'excl' === WC()->cart->tax_display_cart ) : ?>
            <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo sanitize_title( $code ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php _e( 'Recurring Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>



    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: maybe you forgot  some code ?

Comment: Can you share the link to see the code behind?

Comment: You need to indent code in order for it to render properly.

Comment: It will be better to have all the template `review-order.php` code to see exactly where you have add your text (and also a screenshot for that repetition). I think you don't need to add your text in that template, instead it will be a better and cleaner solution to use woocommerce hooks, for that purpose. Could you indicate in your question where you want to display this text exactly?

Comment: I just posted the entire code above. I added the code at the very top of it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just wanted to bump this (it's my first time on here so not sure if I'm doing this right). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!!! @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, it is better to use woocommerce hooks *(without editing `review-order.php` template)*:

You need to use (pasting this code in the function.php file of your active child theme or theme):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'my_wc_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
function my_wc_checkout_before_order_review() {
    echo '<p class="return-to-cart">If you\'d like to change your subscription, go back to <a href="'. WC()->cart->get_cart_url() .'">Cart</a>.</p>';
}
```

This works perfectly *(tested)*, no more repetition.  `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review` hook add something just after "Order summary" title.

You can manage styling with `.return-to-cart` class in your style.css file located in your active child theme or theme:

```css
.return-to-cart{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

If your website is multilingual you can set it with gettex this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'my_wc_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
function my_wc_checkout_before_order_review() {
    echo '<p class="return-to-cart">'.__("If you'd like to change your subscription, go back to ", "your_theme_domain").'<a href="'. WC()->cart->get_cart_url() .'">'.__("Cart", "woocommerce").'.</a></p>';
}
```

Replacing `your_theme_domain` by your theme slug. Like this you will be able to translate it in many languages.

Comment: Wow that worked great! Thanks so much. One additional question: In order to do the styling portion that you mentioned above, should I copy style.css into my child folder, then open the file & try to find .return-to-cart in that file? I just tried searching for .return-to-cart in that file, but couldn't find it. I'm just using a text editor to open these files. Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Clicked the check mark! Thanks for all of your help @LoicTheAztec! First time here & seems like a great community.

Comment: Done! @LoicTheAztec